# How to disable search dialog in SearchView

Tags: android, search, searchview

I've noticed that on some devices the SearchView opens a special full-screen dialog with dedicated `Search` button in it when the view with SearchView is shown for the user. I would like to avoid it at do not show this dialog. I want my SearchView to behave similarly to `EditText`. Because below it, I have a listView which is changing content and user need to see it.
This is how I set up my `SearchView` in XML:

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/search_view_guests"
    android:background="@drawable/search_view"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Type in username..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

And this is how I use it in the code:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Call<List<User>> call = retrofit.listUsers(null, null, newText);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                    usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
                    usersList.addAll(response.body());
                    InvAdapter adapter = new InvAdapter(
                            getContext(),
                            R.layout.list_view_invitation_item,
                            usersList
                    );
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            User user = (User) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            if(!temporaryInvited.contains(user)) {
                                markAsInvited(view);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

@Edit

This the default view which i can see on some devices (relatively smaller)
[image]

Comment: `SearchView opens a special full-screen dialog` Can you show an example like gif or something? However you have set a custom background, that might cause the issue?

Comment: @Mohsen I uploaded the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen
```